# Animation Issue in ListView

Tags: android, listview, animation

List View gets slow, when using animation in list item. I have added some property in android xml list. I have added animation in list view adapter class. i have used below code

```
holder.footerRow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.animator.slide_down);
if(a != null){
    a.reset();
    if(holder.footerRow != null){
        holder.footerRow.clearAnimation();
        holder.footerRow.startAnimation(a);
    }
    // ...
```

**XML:**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animationCache="false"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:visibility="visible" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? Please have a look through: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see what makes a good question.

Answer (score 0):

`loadAnimation` is slow. It is parsing XML from your resources. You only need to call it **once** in your adapter - just store it in a member variable. If it is still slow, post your animation XML. How many listview items are you trying to animate at the same time?